# How to call window load event on specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call windows.load event on specific page. I am doing like this ..

```
$(window).load(function(){

  if(document.URL == "/car-driving.html")
  {
    overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    $('.popup').show();    
    return false;
  }
});
```

Here I am trying to show overlay based on page load, but its not working. If I remove `if condition` then overlay is showing in every page. How to make it specific to only my car-driving.html page so that if anyone visit car-driving.html page, then it will show overlay ?

Comment: The `document` has no property `URL`. Try `window.location.href` or `window.location.path`.

Comment: Use `location.pathname` instead of `document.URL`.

Comment: @BenM i tried `if(window.location.href == "/car-driving.html")` but its not working

Comment: Because `window.location.href` contains the WHOLE URL, including the domain and protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 if (window.location.href.match('car-driving.html') != null) {
   overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
   $('.popup').show();    
   return false;
  }
```

Hope It Helps

Answer (score 0):

document.URL returns the whole url ex: "h t t p : / / stackoverflow.com/questions/17970734/how-to-call-window-load-event-on-specific-page"

You'll have to use a regex match or indexOf

**edit** or better yet

```
document.location.pathname ==
```

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying the value of the href in an alert and you will see what you need to match:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(window.location.href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i Use this and working well for me

```js
<script> 
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#onload').modal('show');
        }, 10000);
    }

    function delayer() {
        window.location = 'Your Desired URL';
    }
);
</script>
```

Here .model is my popup div class